# Arrows on edges in a graph using Networkx

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, networkx

I have a graph with nodes and edges. The code colors the array `Edges` with the array `Weights` as shown in the current output. Is it possible to put arrows on the array elements in `Edges` as displayed in the expected output? I want arrows on specific edges according to `Edges`, not all.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable

N = 1

def pos():
    x, y = 1, N + 3 - 1
    for _ in range(2 * N * (N + 1)):
        yield (x, y)
        y -= (x + 2) // (N + 3)
        x = (x + 2) % (N + 3)

G = nx.Graph()
it_pos = pos()
for u in range(2 * N * (N + 1)):
    G.add_node(u + 1, pos=next(it_pos))
    if u % (2 * N + 1) < N:
        for v in (u - 2 * N - 1, u - N - 1, u - N):
            if G.has_node(v + 1):
                G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)
    elif u % (2 * N + 1) == N:
        G.add_edge(u + 1, u - N + 1)
    elif u % (2 * N + 1) < 2 * N:
        for v in (u - 1, u - N - 1, u - N):
            G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)
    else:
        for v in (u - 1, u - N - 1):
            G.add_edge(u + 1, v + 1)


nx.draw(G, nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'), with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
Edges=np.array([[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]])
Weights=np.array([[1.7],[2.9],[8.6]])
flat_weights = Weights.flatten()
weights_normalized = [x / max(flat_weights) for x in flat_weights]
edge_weight_map = dict(zip([tuple(e) for e in Edges.tolist()],weights_normalized))
my_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('Oranges')
colors = my_cmap([edge_weight_map.get(tuple(e), 0) for e in Edges.tolist()])
pos = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos')
sm = ScalarMappable(cmap=my_cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(0,max(flat_weights)))
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edge_color=colors, 
                       edgelist=[tuple(e) for e in Edges.tolist()],
                       width=5);

plt.colorbar(sm)
```

The current output is

[image]

The expected output is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there.

First, you will need to create a directed graph instead of an undirected graph:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
```

Second, `DiGraph` objects are plotted with arrow heads by default, so you need to specify `arrows=False` in the call to `nx.draw(...)`.

```
nx.draw(G, nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'), with_labels=True, font_weight='bold', arrows=False)
```

If you now plot your selected edges separately, they come with arrow heads (per default).

[image]